# I am trying to make a field show and save from quickedit screen

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic, customization

I have a select box with some options. It appears in the normal product edit screen with the following code.

```
function we_skroutzxml_custom_availability() {
    woocommerce_wp_select(
        array(
            'id'          => 'we_skroutzxml_custom_availability',
            'placeholder' => __('Choose',$this->plugin_slug),
            'label'       => __('Availability',$this->plugin_slug),
            'options' => array( '' => __( 'Default', $this->plugin_slug ),'Άμεση παραλαβή / Παράδoση 1 έως 3 ημέρες' => __( 'Available in store / Delivery 1 to 3 days', $this->plugin_slug ),'Παράδοση σε 1 - 3 ημέρες' => __( 'Delivery 1 to 3 days', $this->plugin_slug ),'Παράδοση σε 4 - 10 ημέρες' => __( 'Delivery 4 to 10 days', $this->plugin_slug ), 'Κατόπιν Παραγγελίας' => __( 'Upon order', $this->plugin_slug ))
    ));
}

function we_skroutzxml_custom_availability_save_data($post_id) {
    $custom_availability = $_POST['we_skroutzxml_custom_availability'];
    if ( ! empty( $custom_availability ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'we_skroutzxml_custom_availability',$custom_availability);
    }else {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'we_skroutzxml_custom_availability');
    }
}
```

What must i do to show it in the quickedit screen and save it as well?Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your quick edit custom box:

```
function display_custom_quickedit_book( $column_name, $post_type ) {
    // it would be a good idea to add a nonce here
    ?>
    <fieldset class="inline-edit-col-right inline-edit-book">
      <div class="inline-edit-col column-<?php echo $column_name; ?>">
        <label class="inline-edit-group">
        <!-- here goes your input -->
        </label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'quick_edit_custom_box', 'display_custom_quickedit_book', 10, 2 );
```

And then you have to process the input value while saving post. But if that field is already a custom box, then you've already modified `save_post` to process it, I guess...

And there are a few more tricks with setting values and so on. You can read more on that on Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/quick_edit_custom_box